# The Difference between "the means of production" vs "means of production"?

Tags: grammar, possessives

Sometimes I see words like I mentioned that use without using article **the**.
Is there any difference in meaning?

Because as far as I know we should use article the for the possessive form of non-living things and animals.

> For example: **Communism is based on common ownership of the means of production,and communists believe in a classless society.**

My question is that sometimes I see some words like "means of transport/communication/expression", why we don't use "**the** means of transport" instead?

Comment: sorry you really need to extend this question, use the sentences in the title as quotes so we can see what you men better.  If it is about the use of the word "the" there are many many questions already about this.

Comment: I changed it,I hope that make sense

Comment: I think in general we would not use "the".  But because "the means of production" is a famous phrase used by Marx's translator, you always see it with a "the".  I think it is more categorical...  "common ownership of means of production" could imply "we should make some public factories", but "common ownership of the means of production" implies "all the factories should be public".

Comment: Thanks mate,so do I,I think we don't use the in general.